# dashed hopes , dashed lines

Tags: meaning

Actually I was wondering about the literal meaning of the word "dashed" , somewhere along the way I learned that "dashed hopes" meant "shattered hopes" but a dashed line isn't really "shattered" since dashes aren't all over the place , so is there an accurate way to describe this word ?

Answer (score 2):

The word ‘dash’ has several different meanings based on context.

A dashed line is so called because it’s a line made up of dashes; of little straight strokes of the pen/pencil.

‘To dash’ can also be used as a synonym of ‘to run’, although it gives the impression of a much shorter distance — across the room, perhaps — and a lot more speed.

Lastly, if an object *is* ‘dashed’, it tends to mean that it was destroyed or broken apart — dashed hopes, a ship dashed against the rocks, a jar dashed to the ground.

As you can see, there’s no single definition that fits it completely, but several different ones build a comprehensive picture of its usage. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks you for your answer  , It's still a bit confusing actually , when I first heard of "dashed dreams" I couldn't make out the meaning , the first thing that jumped into my head was a dashed line , ‘to run’ makes perfect sense , but what does a shattered dream have to do with dashes , that my question

Comment: @Moha a shattered dream has been ‘dashed’, per the third definition given in my post; it has been *destroyed* or broken into pieces. It has nothing to do with either of the other definitions.

Comment: I get it , so it's a separate definition that has nothing to do with dashes..
thank you again !